# Element type is invalid:expected a string (for built.in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: Object

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, import

Whenever I try to run using react-native run-android I get this error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `AppContainer`.

This is my `render` method where the error occurs:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Drawer 
        ref={(ref)=>this._drawer = ref}
        type="displace"
        content={<View style={{backgroundColor: "#000", height: 1000}}
        />}
        onClose={this.closeDrawer.bind(this)}
        onOpen={this.openDrawer.bind(this)}
        openDrawerOffset={0.2}
        >
        <Navigator
        ref={(ref) => this._navigator = ref}
        configureScene={this.configureScene.bind(this)}
        renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
        />
        </Drawer>

    )
}
```

And this is how I import:

```
import { Drawer, View} from 'native-base'
import Navigator from 'react-native'
```

I tried with `{Navigator}` as well but it just throws a different error, so I think the import is ok now but the problem is somewhere else I think!

Comment: Isn't it `import { NavigatorIOS } from 'react-native'`? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html

Comment: NavigatorIOS? I am using android.

Comment: What is the different error?

Comment: it says that its not expoprted, but nevermind this one because i think its correct this way without curly braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Navigator` is deprecated it was in `react native` version 23 [Navigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/navigator.html)

you can use [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) or [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) or [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation)

Comment: now it shows this error: Route 'configureScene' should declare a screen. For example:   import MyScreen from './MyScreen'; ... configureScene: { screen:MyScreen, }